# Tableau Data store migration to Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, tableau-api

Currently we have a workbook developed in Tableau using Oracle server as the data store where we have all our tables and views. Now we are migrating to Redshift fora better performance. We have the same table structure as in the Oracle with the same table names and the field names in the Redshift. We already have the Tableau workbook developed and we need to point to Redshift tables and views now.  How do we point the developed workbook to Redshift now, kindly help.
Also let me know any other inputs in this regard.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: I have used multiple extracts and used data blending to develop the workbook. So how does the replace data source functionality help in this regard. Your detail explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Replace Data Source](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/replacing-data-source) functionality of Tableau Desktop

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass `Replace Data Source` and move data directly from Oracle to Redshift using bulk loaders.

Simple combo of SQL*Plus + Python + boto + psycopg2 will do the job.
It should:

1. Open read pipe from Oracle SQL*Plus
2. Compress data stream
3. Upload compressed stream to S3
4. Bulk append data from S3 to Redshift table.

You can check example of how to [extract table or query data from Oracle](https://github.com/alexbuz/Oracle-To-Redshift-Data-Loader/blob/master/dist-64bit/include/extractor.py) and then [load it to Redshift](https://github.com/alexbuz/Oracle-To-Redshift-Data-Loader/blob/master/dist-64bit/include/loader.py) using COPY command from S3.